# How to know the list of connections open on a remote MySQL AWS RDS machine

Tags: mysql, rds

Where can I find the list of connections open on a remote MySQL AWS RDS machine

```
netstat -n |grep 3306|grep ESTABLISHED|wc -l
```

I do this to find connections which are ESTABLISHED locally, how do I do this for remote instance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Connect to the MySQL AWS RDS instance and run the command

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

This will list every connection to that MySQL instance, including the host and the port. It wil also show what command they are currently executing. If you want to see the full command, run

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

[MySQL SHOW PROCESSLIST Reference Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html)